# Apache Cordova InAppBrowser Basic Implementation

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I'm learning Apache Cordova and I'm trying to get the most basic of 'website app frames' going where when I open my app on Android and click a link then a fullscreen google.ca opens up.

I followed the instructions on the official documentation [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#cordovainappbrowseropen)

I was able to get the plugin installed on my project and then I simply added this line, based on that same documentation, which I thought would open up google.ca

```
<a href="#" onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.google.ca', '_blank', 'location=yes');">Open Link</a>
```

Nothing happens when I click the link, I think I'm missing something small but I've scanned through the rest of the documentation and can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.ca', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;" > Open Link</a>
```

Of course you must install:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Important notes

window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_system’);       Loads in the system browser

window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’);    Loads in the InAppBrowser

window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’, ‘location=no’); Loads in the InAppBrowser with no location bar

window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_self’); Loads in the Cordova web view